# Navigate web pages from php interpreting javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

in the past I have written a php script that continuously fetches an external web page with curl, gets its html, parses it, and stores some "caught" numbers in a database.

Now such external web page has evolved: those number are no longer "static" (meaning: constants in the page's html, or generated from server scripting), they are generated after a non-trivial javascript scripting after the web page is ready, involving also ajax call.
So, I can't use curl anymore.

What can I use to get those "numbers" AFTER javascript has completed its calculations and calls? I'd like to write all in php, but if needed I may use some other language (on unix) and call it from php.

What do you recommend? Can it be done or is it a hell?

(P.S.: I'm afraid some of you may think I may be doing something "illegal" but it's nothing like that, the "external website" belongs to my company.)

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you looked at something like phantomjs? Since it acts like a browser, all the required JS will fire off after the page load. It's not in PHP, but the tutorials on the http://phantomjs.org/ page might get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks, phantomjs is definitely the right way!